# Number of Chapter - Title Chapter fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to use this style in my fancy header:

> Number of Chapter - Title of Chapter

i.e: **1 - Chapter Name**

I use this command, but I view only the title of chapter.

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
```

How can I add the number of chapter ?

Comment: Please don't post fragments only.

Comment: If "#1" is "1 - Chapter Name", it should be OK. Could you please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @Stephen: It depends on the `documentclass` what `#1` might be, so you're right: we need a MWE

Comment: I don't understand why the `\leftmark` should appear in the center of the head?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I use "book" {oneside} class, and i want to print at center of my header, the number of chapter and the title. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Well, you are right, my comment was too short. What I wanted to say was: We do not know when/where/how `\chaptermark` is used with which argument, thus without MWE it is not clear where (or whether) to add `\thechapter{} - ` (or to change something else).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks a lot. I have resolved the issue with:
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\textit{\thechapter{} - \leftmark}}}

Answer (score 3):

A trial: I assume that the left mark should be empty (or it should use another style at least).

The `\chaptermark{}` must be redefined at begin of the `\document` body, otherwise the standard definition of `\@chapapp.~#1` etc. is used.

Please note that the chapter start page is using another pagestyle, i.e. `plain`.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{%
\def\chaptermark#1{%
  \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
      \bfseries\thechapter~--~ %
      \fi
      \fi
      #1}}{}}%
}

\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{}

\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First one}
\blindtext[5]
\section{A section}
\chapter{Next chapter}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting output from compiling the given code]

Answer (score 0):

[`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) is also a viable option for setting *titles* of sectional units in the header.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{titleps,lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newpagestyle{main}{
  \sethead{}      % left
          {\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne\if@mainmatter
             \bfseries \thechapter~--~\chaptertitle
          \fi\fi} % center
          {}      % right
}
\g@addto@macro{\frontmatter}{\setheadrule{0pt}}
\g@addto@macro{\mainmatter}{\clearpage\setheadrule{.4pt}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\sloppy% Just for this example
\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{First section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[11-20]
\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{First section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-30]
\chapter{Last chapter}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{First section}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[31-40]

\end{document}
```

It's good to review the [quick guide](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/titleps_fancyhdr.html) as it show-cases the difference in input between [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and `titleps`.